# Struts2 Validation Redirect Action Input - FieldErrors are Gone

Tags: java, struts2

Below is my configuration for interceptors:

```
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="storeStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>

        <interceptor-stack name="retrieveStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>

        <interceptor-stack name="appDefaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
                <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
                <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
```

And my action:

```
    <action name="update/*" class="comics.comics.ComicsAction" method="view">
        <interceptor-ref name="retrieveStack" />
        <param name="key">{1}</param>
        <result>/comics/comics-chapters.jsp</result>
    </action>


    <action name="add" class="comics.comics.ChapterAction" method="add">
        <interceptor-ref name="storeStack" />
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="parse">true</param>
            <param name="key">${key}</param>
            <param name="actionName">update</param>
            <param name="namespace">/comics</param>    
        </result>

        <result name="input" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="parse">true</param>
            <param name="key">${key}</param>
            <param name="actionName">update</param>
            <param name="namespace">/comics</param>    
        </result>

    </action>
```

In my comics-chapters.jsp page, field errors are gone. But when i change the input result to:

```
         <result name="input">/comics/comics-chapters.jsp</result>
```

field errors are displayed.

How to display field errors when my input result is an action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when you are using `redirectAction`, Struts2 is creating a new request and response object and will clear the value stack and place new request and response in the value stack so it will overwrite the previous data.

You have few options here

1. Store your messages in the action and on the `redirectAction` you can fetch them from the action and show them to the user.
2. use [MessageStoreInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/MessageStoreInterceptor.html)

There is a long pending request for scope result which will be able to handle such use-cases, but i believe its coming in struts-3.x (a.k.a 2.5) version.

Comment: @JRGalia:Yes its there, but with `FlashResult`,its like storing your object in HTTP redirect and let user do things more easily,configuring `MessageStoreInterceptor` is really a bit tricky.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, what u mean by FlashResult?

Comment: @JRGalia:The `FlashResult` basically works like the ServletActionRedirectResult except that instead of converting all extra parameters to strings and adding them as HTTP parameters in the redirect URL, it creates a HashMap using these parameter key/value pairs with no conversion and stores it in the user session.  On the next HTTP request the FlashInterceptor, if properly added to the interceptor stack, will retrieve this map and copy the map entries to the target action using the parameter keys.Its more easy than the `MessageStoreInterceeptor`.A JIRA ticket is already there.

Comment: The link to MessageStoreInterceptor is a 404

Answer (score 1):

try put `store` interceptor on top of `defaultStack` like this:

```
<interceptor-stack name="storeStack">
         <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
         </interceptor-ref>
         <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>

</interceptor-stack>

<interceptor-stack name="retrieveStack">
         <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
         </interceptor-ref>
         <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>

 </interceptor-stack>
```

please ***Always*** notice the order of interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

As Umesh says the redirectAction which you have specified as result causes the error messages to be cleared from the value stack when the new action is called. Another option you have though in this case is to use the [Chain](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/chain-result.html) result. The chain result causes another action to be called keeping all existing values in the value stack except error messages, for which you will have to use the [ChainingInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/chain-result.html).
You can also see [this blog post](http://chrisiecorner.blogspot.gr/2012/09/struts2-action-patterns.html) for more details on how to use the chain result and ChainingInterceptor.

Comment: As a rule, Action Chaining is not recommended. First explore other options, such as the Redirect After Post technique. Ref:http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/action-chaining.html. Instead it's better to use messageStore Interceptor.

Comment: the blog post does not exist.